# How to create a html file offline with app cache

Tags: html, cache

We have an online html file that is accessible through the browser, we want this to be available offline and looking in to it the best thing would be using the App Cache with a manifest file.

I believe i have done all the steps correctly but it still doesn't preload all the files for the html. Here is what i have done:

1. Updated the html tag to read

   html manifest="*location of manifest file*"
2. Created a manifest file listing the individual files

   ```
    CACHE MANIFEST    
    1360_VT_04data\1360_VT_03.js    
    1360_VT_04data\1360_VT_03.swf    
    1360_VT_04data\1360_VT_03.xml    
    1360_VT_04data\1360_VT_03_core.xml
   ```

   etc....
3. Edited the .htaccess file with

   ```
    AddType text/cache-manifest .manifest
    ExpiresByType application/x-web-app-manifest+json   "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest                   "access plus 1 year"
   ```

Any ideas why this is not working?

Answer (score 2):

[App Cache is deprecated.](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/6192449487634432)

I recommend you look into its successor, Service Workers.

Here's an example for doing an offline page:
https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/service-worker/custom-offline-page/

Comment: thanks will take a look!